# selenium cakephp phpunit Has anyone got it to work?

Tags: php, selenium, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.x

I have installed the selenium server and I have it running. I used composer to install both phpunit-selenium and facebook (selenium plugin).

When I run the test I get the same error fatal error: Class XXdriverXX not found.

This happens with all the classes.

I have searched the internet and there is almost no information on selenium in cakephp.

My question is simple. Has anyone got selenium to work with cakephp. If so how did you do it?

I am using wamp and cakephp3.

Thank you

```
enter code here
<?php

namespace App\Test\TestCase\Acceptance;

class UserSubscriptionTestFB extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * @var RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected $webDriver;

    public function setUp()
{
    $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities::firefox());
}


public function tearDown()
{
    $this->webDriver->quit();
}

public function fillFormAndSubmit($inputs)
{
    $this->webDriver->get('http://vaprobash.dev/');
    $form = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('subscriptionForm'));

    foreach ($inputs as $input => $value) {
        $form->findElement(WebDriverBy::name($input))->sendKeys($value);
    }

    $form->submit();
}

public function testValidFormSubmission(array $inputs)
{
    $this->fillFormAndSubmit($inputs);

    $content = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::tagName('body'))->getText();
    $this->assertEquals('Everything is Good!', $content);
}

}
```

Comment: Posting a code example from your test would be helpful, there's nothing 'hardcoded' about cake and selenium. You don't really need phpunit-selenium, you can use phpunit standalone and Page Objects

Comment: this is an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not specifying the full path to Facebook's web driver.

```
<?php

namespace App\Test\TestCase\Acceptance;

use \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use \Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy

class UserSubscriptionTestFB extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
....
```

Comment: Thank you the-noob. I thought there must be a use statement missing but I didn't know which ones or how to structure them.

Comment: On the thread that had the tutorial there were so many people with this problem.

Comment: well, feel free to link the solution in that forum post it directly :)